# Ant start target after

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ant, build

In my ant script, I have target, which zipped a project. How can I start another target after this target finished?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: have you tried with `<antcall>`?

Comment: As reflected in the answers, the idiomatic way to do this is to have the final step declare its dependencies and call that. That way you can call `next-target` if you want the normal run, or just `zip-target` if you for some reason want just the zip file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's assume the target you have is `zip-project` and the next target you want to execute is `next-target-for-something`

**One way of doing this is using** `antcall`

```
 <target name="zip-project">
     <!-- Your Zipping Task-->
     <antcall target="next-target-for-something"/>
 </target>
```

**Remember** `antcall` **can be invoked inside a** `target` **only**

**Another way of doing this is using** `depends`
You would have something like:

```
<target name="zip-project" >
     <!-- Your Zipping Task-->
</target>
```

Now define the next task as

```
<target name="next-target-for-something" depends="zip-project" >
     <!-- Your Next Task-->
</target>
```

though this works in **opposite** manner of what you would have asked. So you need to call the ant like...

```
ant -buildfile <build.xml> next-target-for-something
```

and it will make sure that first `zip-project` is completed and then `next-target-for-something` will be executed.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I'm using eclipse and I run the script using Ctrl + F11, so `antcall` is more suitable for me, since I don't need to change the Run Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use depencencies to achive this. Here is an example:

```
<target name="nextstep" depends="target">
[Do what ever ...]
</target>
```

This will run after target has been finished if you run "ant nextstep".