# execute target on finish

Tags: java, ant

Are there any way to execute a target when execution finishes? I have a set of targets each of which may be called from command line. I need to perform some cleanup target when execution finishes.

I could use `antcall` but that is cumbersome to write that one for every target. Is there more convenient way?

Answer (score 0):

There were questions [like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830542/ant-start-target-after) on stackoverflow. So in general, yes, you have two possibilites:

- Use `antcall`
- Create another target that depends on yours and on your 'clean' target.

About usability of antcall: you will need to be able to specify after which exactly target your should execute this target, you can not avoid it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do it.

Write a custom ant task, in which:

extends Ant's `Task`, implements the `BuildListener` or `SubBuilderListener` interface,

```
public class ListenerTask extends Task implements SubBuildListener {
}
```

calls your specified target (or write the clean up code directly in Java) in `buildFinished` method,

```
@Override
public void buildFinished(BuildEvent be) {
    Target target = (Target)getProject().getTargets().get("Name-To-Your-CleanUp-Target");
    // run the target
    target.performTasks();
}
```

and, of course, registers itself to the project at the very beginning of the build.

```
@Override
public void execute() throws BuildException {
    // addBuildListener will check if the listener has been added
    getProject().addBuildListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to have a default target that performs the desired execution sequence

```
<project name="demo" default="build">
    ..
    ..
    <target name="build" depends="init, do-something, do-something-else, clean"/>

</project>
```